# Strange dot in each page that use ionic v1 and angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I don't know the reason why, but at each of page of my webapp, at the left side upper there is a dot like this:

[image: dot]

It's an html problem I think, in fact running the snippet below you can see that:

```html
<ion-view view-title="Invia feedback">
  <ion-content class="ioncontentcatalog">
    <li>
        <h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;" ng-if=logged>Invia feedback</h2> 
        <h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;" ng-if=!logged>Per poter mandare un feedback devi registrarti!</h2> 
        <form name="feedback">
            <div class="list" ng-if=logged>
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5" ng-model="feedbacktext" required></textarea>
                    </label>
                    <label ng-show="feedback.$invalid"> Scrivi qualcosa </label>
                    <label class="item">
                      <button class="button button-block button-positive"  ng-disabled="feedback.$invalid" ng-click="send(feedbacktext)">Invia</button>
                    </label>            
            </div>
        </form>
      </li>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

However, I put also the controller of this page:

```js
.controller('SendFeedbackCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, restService) {
   var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
   $scope.tknuser = JSON.parse(token);
   $scope.logged = false;
    
   $scope.feedbackform = { 
       message: "adad",
       readfb: false,
       user: {
                  iduser: -1
                }
   };
```

And also the class style used:

```css
.ioncontentcatalog {
            background-image: url('../img/background.png')
        }
```

That's very strange and I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `li` decoration like this:

```
<li style="list-style-type: none;">
```

Comment: ohhh, that's the problem!! Oh now I have understand! Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri inline-style is kind hack and you have to apply to each `li` element, for best practice add a CSS rule to your style sheet fix it for all.

Comment: Sure, I have added inline style just for example

Comment: Thanks. Then just to delete it, but @DanielH why I have to modify my CSS? It's enough to delete <li>

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri if you don't need the li, just remove it, make sure it is not code added by other lib

Comment: Yes I don't need I can delete it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It is the `li` default style, add this CSS rule to remove it:

> ## list-style
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style

```css
.ioncontentcatalog li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Invia feedback">
  <ion-content class="ioncontentcatalog">
    <li>
        <h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;" ng-if=logged>Invia feedback</h2> 
        <h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;" ng-if=!logged>Per poter mandare un feedback devi registrarti!</h2> 
        <form name="feedback">
            <div class="list" ng-if=logged>
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5" ng-model="feedbacktext" required></textarea>
                    </label>
                    <label ng-show="feedback.$invalid"> Scrivi qualcosa </label>
                    <label class="item">
                      <button class="button button-block button-positive"  ng-disabled="feedback.$invalid" ng-click="send(feedbacktext)">Invia</button>
                    </label>            
            </div>
        </form>
      </li>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```